# Swift ForEach loop with \.self

Tags: swift

I have a chat model:

```
struct Chat: Encodable, Decodable {
    var messageId: String
    var textMessage: String
    var avatarUrl: String
    var photoUrl: String
    var senderId: String
    var username: String
    var date: Double
}
```

Im using ForEach to loop over like so:

```
ForEach(chatViewModel.chatArray, id: \.messageId) { chat in
     VStack(alignment: .leading) {
         TextMessageRow(chat: chat)
     }.padding(.top,20)
}
```

There are some cases where `messageId` won't be in the db (or empty) this is causing an issue bringing the data back from `firestore`

So I tried with `self`:

```
ForEach(chatViewModel.chatArray, id: \.self) { chat in
         VStack(alignment: .leading) {
             TextMessageRow(chat: chat)
         }.padding(.top,20)
    }
```

And i get the following:

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Chat' conform to 'Hashable'
```

The value not being present in the db is causing an error when its not available, is there anything else I can use? to make it not use `messageId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` expects a ID which needs to be hashable, so it uniquely identify the view and reload it specifically when there is a change in associated object, if your `messageID` can be empty sometimes, you can try using some other field of `Chat` which you think is unique may be `textMessage`?

`ForEach(chatViewModel.chatArray, id: \.textMessage) { chat in`

OR

Because all the properties in your `Chat` data model already confirms to `Hashable` protocol, you can simply make your `Chat` model hashable by specifying

```
struct Chat: Encodable, Decodable, Hashable {
    var messageId: String
    var textMessage: String
    var avatarUrl: String
    var photoUrl: String
    var senderId: String
    var username: String
    var date: Double
}
```

OR

But if you dont want all the properties of the data model to participate in the calculation of hash value and want to use specific property values you can call `combine` repeatedly with those property as shown below

```
struct Chat: Encodable, Decodable, Hashable {
    var messageId: String
    var textMessage: String
    var avatarUrl: String
    var photoUrl: String
    var senderId: String
    var username: String
    var date: Double

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(messageId)
        hasher.combine(textMessage)
        hasher.combine(senderId)
    }
}
```

Now you can use `ForEach(chatViewModel.chatArray, id: \.self) { chat in`

For more details into `Hashable` protocol, you can check https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-conform-to-the-hashable-protocol

Comment: @gurumukh Singh: did answer help? Or you are still facing issues?